# 404 Not Found after updating route in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, laravel-6

I am new to Laravel and I had updated my route in my project.

The initial route was:

```
Route::get('/{todo}', 'TodosController@show');
```

And I had changed it to this:

```
Route::get('/todos/{todo}', 'TodosController@show');
```

I had saved my file but now it is giving 404 Not Found Error.

I had created a new todo task but the url is redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/16

The url should redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/todos/16.

I am stuck.

Could someone please clarify me what did I do wrong and what will be the solution?

Comment: try running `php artisan route:clear` and revisit the page

Comment: What url you are trying?

Comment: @FahdYousri Not working

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... The url should redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/todos/16 but it is currently redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/16

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... That is what I am exactly asking!

Comment: @RemanBala did given solution  worked for you?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... It didn't

Comment: I guess you have share your code now so we can figure out problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Laravel's [named-routes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#named-routes)

```
Route::get('/todos/{todo}', 'TodosController@show')->name('todo');
```

In Blade, you can use this route as

```
{{route('todo', $todo->id)}}
```

Comment: This is working! Thank you. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Sure @RemanBala, Laravel allows you to generate/define the name of a particular route. The `name()` allows you to do that. ie you can specify a name and call it by its name only. While calling it you can use the route name like `{{route('todo', $todo->id)}}` where `todo` is the name of the route and `$todo->id` is the parameter required by the route.  
You can find more detail about Laravel routing below 
1. https://dev.to/kris/all-you-need-to-know-about-route-in-laravel5-d91
2. Laravel Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing